# How to handle CORS policy issue on Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http

The project is just a frontend one no server side language is used , I want to get live data from blockchain charts and I have seen answers for similar questions and answers but on other frameworks . None has been specified for angular . I created a proxy.conf.json file in the src folder and added the following code but still getting the same error when I inspect the browser

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I have added the proxy.conf.jason file to the serve section under angular.json but I still keep getting the error :

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.blockchain.info/charts/transactions-per-second?timespan=5weeks&rollingAverage=8hours&format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource "

This is my ApiService class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpclient : HttpClient ) { }

    public dailychart(){
       return this.httpclient.get('https://api.blockchain.info/charts/transactions-per-second?timespan=5weeks&rollingAverage=8hours&format=json');
     }

}
```

Comment: How are you running your app?  Is this the build and deployed version?  Proxy only works in development.

Comment: @zero298 i'm in development mode

Answer (score 0):

Api.Blockchain' documentation says

Query API Plaintext query api to retreive data from blockchain.info
**Some API calls are available with CORS headers** if you add a **&cors=true** paramter to the GET request

You can see rest of documentation here https://www.blockchain.com/api/q

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you configure your proxy.  Please take a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) because it looks like you just dropped in the example proxy without actually configuring it. Also note that you will still need to deal with CORS issues for **production** as this only works while running the Angular development server.

However, while developing, you need to change your proxy file such that you define a dummy endpoint that will pretend to be the endpoint of the actual resource and then use that dummy endpoint in your code.

So, for you, change `proxy.conf.json` to

```
{
    "/blockchain-info": {
        "target": "https://api.blockchain.info",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

and `ApiService` to:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}

  public dailychart() {
    return this.httpclient.get('/blockchain-info/charts/transactions-per-second?timespan=5weeks&rollingAverage=8hours&format=json');
  }
}
```

You can see that we don't try to make calls directly to `https://api.blockchain.info` anymore.  Instead, we make them to the proxy we registered as `/blockchain-info`.  Now when Angular sees that you are making requests to `/blockchain-info`, it will make the non-CORS-triggering request (outside of the browser) to the correct URL for you.